# link on top half of page won't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I know this a rather specific question and basic html question, but it's been happening on a few of my pages now, and I'm curious as to what exactly is going on.

I have a series of div boxes lined up vertically on a page, each one contains a picture that is a link to a different page on the website. The problem is when I add more than 3 of these div boxes, suddenly all the links on above the bottom three stop working.

http://webstage.emich.edu/dining-new/locations/easterneateries.php

I've tried the same code in jsfiddle, as seen below:

```css
.locationsbx {
    position:absolute;
    width: 540px;
    height:70px;
    z-index:5;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #363636;
    margin-top:110px;
}
.primetriangle {
    border-top:25px solid green;
    height: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    z-index:3;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    z-index:5;
    border-top-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="locationsbx" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="primetriangle" style="z-index: 4;"></div> <a href="/dining-new/locations/eateries/estreetgrill.php"><img style="width: 85px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -18px;" src="/dining-new/images/eateries/estreet.png" alt="" /></a>

    <div class="text" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: -35px; width: 430px;">text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 45px; width: 320px;">
        <img style="height: 35px;" src="/dining-new/images/open.png" alt="" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/menu.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu.png';" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/nutrition.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition.png';" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="locationsbx" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 130px;">
    <div class="primetriangle" style="z-index: 4;"></div> <a href="/dining-new/locations/eateries/sunsetstrips.php"><img style="width: 85px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -18px;" src="/dining-new/images/eateries/sunsetstripslogo.png" alt="" /></a>

    <div class="text" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: -35px; width: 430px;">text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 45px; width: 320px;">
        <img style="height: 35px;" src="/dining-new/images/open.png" alt="" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/menu.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu.png';" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/nutrition.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition.png';" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="locationsbx" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top:240px;">
    <div class="primetriangle" style="z-index: 4;"></div> <a href="/dining-new/locations/eateries/freshens.php"><img style="width: 85px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -18px;" src="/dining-new/images/eateries/sunsetstripslogo.png" alt="" /></a>

    <div class="text" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: -35px; width: 430px;">text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 45px; width: 320px;">
        <img style="height: 35px;" src="/dining-new/images/open.png" alt="" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/menu.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu.png';" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/nutrition.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition.png';" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="locationsbx" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 350px;">
    <div class="primetriangle" style="z-index: 4;"></div> <a href="/dining-new/locations/eateries/uppercrust.php"><img style="width: 85px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -18px;" src="/dining-new/images/eateries/sunsetstripslogo.png" alt="" /></a>

    <div class="text" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: -35px; width: 430px;">text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 45px; width: 320px;">
        <img style="height: 35px;" src="/dining-new/images/open.png" alt="" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/menu.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/menu.png';" />
        <img style="margin-left: 2px; height: 35px; display: inline;" src="/dining-new/images/nutrition.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/dining-new/images/nutrition.png';" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and it's working fine there- so I'm confused as to what might be some of the reasons why putting the code on the actual server would be causing problems with disabling the links.

### Any thoughts/explanations would be super super appreciated

**NOTE: I am well aware that it is not in good form to have inline styles, especially when I have the external CSS sheet anyways. However, the inline styles are just there until I can resolve the actual problem with the links.
** ALSO: The link to the page is very obviously under construction still. I have been dealing with the disabled links over multiple pages now and am much more concerned with why they're disabling than the rest of the page

Comment: So I looked through your code, thinking something may not have been closed. After messing around, I realized that if you `display:none` on the side bar to the right (style2info), your buttons will work.

I would check around there, it looks like you may have them covered by a `<div>`.

That would be your first place to check.

Comment: I bet no one can really answer your question, suggestions: 1) remove any position absolute in the css if you can. 2) do not use inline styles. 3) [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) your html code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a table for the "Dining Categories" bar, and if that's the section you're talking about, only the first image is wrapped in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

I went to check the source of your page you linked to and you're not closing the <`div`> with the `class="locationsbx"` on your page. I think you're doing in the code you pasted above but not on the actual page.

**EDIT:** Not really a complete answer. I would have just left a comment but I need 50 points for that, I don't have those.

Comment: It's pretty much unanswerable without all her code. Also the use of inline styles really makes it bad to work with. You have the basic idea. She has an absolute positioned div covering an unclosed div.